# Android: overriding onPause and onResume - proper way

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

When overriding the `onPause()` and the `onResume()` methods of the activity, where is the proper location to call the `super.onPause()` and `super.onResume()`? At the beginning of the method or at the end?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks:

> Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work, as shown in the examples above.

So, for lifecycle callbacks, like `onPause()` and `onResume()`, we should do `super.onPause()` or `super.onResume()` at the very beginning. For other methods, it all depends on the semantics of the super class.

Comment: @espinchi I added an update to the accepted answer, pointing to this one. No way to tell if it will be allowed to go public or not. I do hope so.

Comment: great resource, answers my question exactly. Marking as accepted answer.

Comment: This is probably still best practice, but the documentation doesn't appear to say so anymore

Answer (score 18):

**Update:** This is the accepted answer and it contains a nice amount of good information, including a useful diagram, pulled together into one place. However, it appears to be *incorrect*, at least according to the current Android documentation which, as the poster points out, is the ultimate source for information on the SDK. Possibly the documentation was clarified after this answer was posted. But, in any case, don't stop reading with this answer, check out [espinchi's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20805556/165164). It has the documentation on its side.

---

Placement of the `super` methods depends only on your preference. It would only matter if those methods were taking parameters OR if you were doing some concurrent work. For example if you do this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        try {
            someOtherThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.e(e);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

it might block the thread and prevent `super` from being called.

I suggest that you should read all documentation available because they will help you much. For example this is what you can find in the `onPause` javadoc. I bolded out the important parts:

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going
>   into the background, but has not (yet) been killed. The counterpart to
>   onResume().
>
> When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will
>   be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so
>   be sure to not do anything lengthy here.
>
> This **callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the
>   activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user
>   and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to
>   start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a
>   good place to do things like stop animations and other things that
>   consume a noticeable amount of CPU** in order to make the switch to the
>   next activity as fast as possible, or to close resources that are
>   exclusive access such as the camera.
>
> In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused
>   processes to reclaim resources. Because of this, **you should be sure
>   that all of your state is saved by the time you return from this
>   function**. In general onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is used to save
>   per-instance state in the activity and this method is used to store
>   global persistent data (in content providers, files, etc.)
>
> After receiving this call you will usually receive a following call to
>   onStop() (after the next activity has been resumed and displayed),
>   however in some cases there will be a direct call back to onResume()
>   without going through the stopped state.
>
> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

I do recommend this flowchart for you it will help your development tremendously:

[image: Android Activity Flowchart]

Comment: I pretty understand the life cycle. And I read this exact javadoc before I asked the question :) What I didn't understand, whether calling the super before or after can actually affect my code inside the methods in regards to locks / initializations of the android itself.

Comment: Can you present an example about what you are thinking?

Comment: For example, I am using the standard android's SoundPool. And onPause i call SoundPool.release(). I call super.onPause in the end of the function. Sometimes the application hangs on this exact call SoundPool.release(). Is it something with the lifecycle or with SoundPool itself? I ask this, because SoundPool is not the only example for this behavior.

Comment: Well I never experienced hangs with `onPause` or `onResume` if the code I called was running in the same thread so my guess is that when you call `release` it has some concurrency issues. I did not check the Android framework's source code though.

Comment: changing the accepted answer to espinchi's, after android's documentation clarified the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It probably doesn't matter, but to know for sure, you need to know what the super methods are doing, and usually that information is not available to you.

My style is to call e.g. super.onCreate(), super.onResume(), etc. before the body of my own method, and e.g. super.onPause() and super.onDestroy() after the body of my own method.

The theory behind this is that I like to let the super methods run first while building something up, just in case what I'm doing depends on what the superclass sets up first, and when tearing something down, I like to tear down my own stuff before the superclass tears down its stuff.

Comment: Thats what I also do :)

Comment: This is the right logic to do stuff, when you are thinking in programming language conventions. The question whether this is the case in Android lifecycle?

Comment: I don't think the documentation says (correct me if I'm wrong). If the documentation doesn't say, then there's a good chance that it doesn't matter, but in the absence of better information, I like to play it safe.

Comment: I just noticed espinchi's answer. It looks like Android's best practices are to always call the superclass method at the start.

Answer (score 3):

There's no right or wrong.
That depends on what you do on your implementation of these methods.
Sometimes you'll want the `super` to be before your code, and sometime after.

Comment: You can add an example. It would be great answer then.

Comment: Right.  Sometimes a super's order matters, but in this case it doesn't have any effect one what's going to happen.

Comment: Its really hard to to make a 'thumb rule' for it, but, if you insist - generally you'll want super.onCreate to be the first call in your activity and regarding onPause - it depend if you want your logic to happen before or after the activity's becoming not visible to the user

Answer (score 2):

You can put it anywhere. First you have to understand the Activity life cycle. Check the following link [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Download the demo and run it you will be clear

Answer (score 2):

Delving into the android code, you can find that the framework sets a flag called mcalled when you call super.onPause(). This flag is later checked on resume by the framework.

```
if (!mCalled) {
            throw new SuperNotCalledException(
                "Activity " + mComponent.toShortString() +
                " did not call through to super.onResume()");
        }
```

All you need to do is make sure the call is made to super and you are good. No other precaution is necessary.